# Echo two SQL queries in one HTML table

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display information from two queries in one single table, but can't figure out how to make it work.

This is what I got working with one query:

```
    SELECT Company,COUNT(*) as count FROM Employee_Table GROUP BY Company ORDER BY count DESC;

    Company       Employees
    ABC           45
    DEF           15
    GHI           5
```

Now beneath that I'd like to have another query that simply counts all rows, giving me the total amount of Employees.

```
    SELECT Company,COUNT(*) as count FROM Employee_Table GROUP BY Company ORDER BY count DESC;

    SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM Employee_Table;

    Company       Employees
    ABC           40
    DEF           15
    GHI           5

    Total         60
```

This is what my code looks like right now. I defined two extra variables for my extra query that I want to echo out, but believe this is not the proper way to do it as I get an sqlsrv_fetch_array error.

```php
            $query1 = "SELECT Company,COUNT(*) as count FROM Employee_Table GROUP BY Company ORDER BY count DESC;";
            $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Totaal FROM Employee_Table;";
            $result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1);
            $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2);

        echo "<table id='total'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Company</th><th>Amount of employees</th></tr>";
            while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1, $result2)) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
                echo $row["Company"];
                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row["count"];

                echo "</td><td>";
                echo $row["Total"];
                echo "</td></tr>";
            }
            echo "</table>";
```

How can this be achieved? I'd appreciate any help

Comment: select ... UNION ALL select 'total', count(*)...

Comment: you are not using the sqlsrv_fetch_array correctly

Comment: I think no need for second query, you can sum count from first query and then you can use it to display total

Comment: As in combine the two queries as one? I'll look it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this by using only first query

```
$query1 = "SELECT Company,COUNT(*) as count FROM Employee_Table GROUP BY Company ORDER BY count DESC;";

$result1 = mysql_query($conn, $query1);

$total_employee = 0;
echo "<table id='total'>";
echo "<tr><th>Company</th><th>Amount of employees</th></tr>";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $row["Company"];
echo "</td><td>";
echo $row["count"];
$total_employee += $row["count"];
echo "</td><td>";

echo "</td></tr>";
}
echo "<tr><td>Total</td><td>$total_employee</td></tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2):

First correct

> sqlsrv_fetch_array()

see here http://php.net/manual/de/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php

Use just a single query and use mysqli_num_rows() function to count

**$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);**

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one query:

```
$result = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT Company,COUNT(*) as count FROM Employee_Table GROUP BY Company ORDER BY count DESC");

?>
<table id='total'>
    <tr><th>Company</th><th>Amount of employees</th></tr>
<?php
$total = 0;
while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
    $total += $row["count"];
    ?>
    <tr><td><?= $row["Company"] ?></td><td><?= $row["count"] ?></td></tr>
    <?php
}
?>
    <tr><td></td><td><?= $total ?></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code

```
        $query1 = "SELECT Company,COUNT(*) as count FROM Employee_Table GROUP BY Company ORDER BY count DESC;";
        $query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Totaal FROM Employee_Table;";
        $result1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query1);
        $result2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query2);

    echo "<table id='total'>";
    echo "<tr><th>Company</th><th>Amount of employees</th></tr>";
        while ($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1)) {
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row["Company"];
            echo "</td><td>";
            echo $row["count"];

            echo "</td><td>";

            echo "</td></tr>";

        }
        $rows = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result1)
            echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $rows["Total"];
            echo "</td></tr>";
          echo "</table>";
```